# Oauth and excel links

Tags: excel, azure, oauth

We have a web app that used to be authenticated through forms and we changed it to use oauth with azure ad. Some users save links to different pages in the app in excel files. The problem is that since we changed the authentication we get an error when an excel link is clicked : "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnectProtocolInvalidNonceException
IDX10311: RequireNonce is 'true' (default) but validationContext.Nonce is null. A nonce cannot be validated. If you don't need to check the nonce, set OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.RequireNonce to 'false'."

I tried adding the OPTIONS and PROPFIND verb to requestFiltering but no luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the fix from this page :[Microsoft support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/218153)

fixed the problem. We are also looking into changing the SSO cookie policy because we don't want to have every user installing the fix if is not necessary.

Updated 2018.01.18
We updated the OS in the company to windows 10 and the issues reappeared. Implementing this code seems to fix the problem: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/78